# Where is the obb(expansion) file location on a nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1 for development?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a `nexus 5` device running `Android 6.0.1` and I'm developing an app that needs to use expansion files. I am having trouble with where to put the `obb` file on the device for testing!

I'm using `android studio` for development and the app installs on the device, however, it fails because the `obb` file is not present.

I'm sure there is a simple explanation, but I have failed so far!

In android 5 on the same device, it was in the `/mnt/shell/emulated folder`, however that folder does not appear to exist any more in android6

Thanks in advance for any help